# Javascript - how to make 'a' element as link using 'href' as variable

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink

I have this code:

```
var a, link;

link = "books/" + this.model.get("id");

a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = link;
```

It creates url for every book. But it outputs it as text. How can I make it output as link, which I could click?

Comment: What do you mean, "it outputs it as text"?  The code you posted creates the `<a>` element but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: can you use from `jQuery`?

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AS3LQ/?

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. As it is, you are not doing anything with the link element, so it's hard to imagine how you'd even see some text.

Comment: @FelixKling: The `.toString()` of a link displays as the text of the `href` property. OP is likely using an `alert(a);`, which calls `.toString()`.

Comment: I'm not using alert(a)

Comment: @Andrius: Well super. You've told us what you're not doing. Now how about showing us what you *are* doing since nothing in your code would result in what you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually appending the element to anything.

```
var a, link;

link = "books/" + this.model.get("id");

a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = link;
a.innerHTML = "something";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: This one works strange. It creates links in one line at the end of document for some reason.

Comment: @Andrius that's because `<a>` elements are **inline content**.  If you want them to be blocks, you can style them with CSS or wrap them in block elements (like `<div>`).

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href",link);

try this

Comment: That would change the URL of the first existing link, not the newly created one.

Comment: use
.lastChild option

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution worked like I needed:

```
link = "books/"+@model.get("id")
a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = link
show = '<a href="'+a+'">show</a>'
```

If anyone would give better solution to just simply output link in a right place, I would choose that as answer.